# Resume a python program after exception?

Tags: python, multithreading

Ok lets say I have this code:

```
name = Bob
try:
    While True:
        print "Whats your name?"
        name = raw_input("Name:")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print name
    raw_input("PRESS ENTER TO RESUME")
```

If I press CTRL-C than enter it closes the program. How could I have the program resume? I am fine with threads but I never have any luck working with them. This will be used for a different larger program, that code is just dummy code. Is what I want even possible?

Comment: you could just put the `try` block inside a `while` loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program terminates because it reaches the end. It has nothing to do with the Keyboard Interrupt. You can just resume the program's execution by... putting some code below that block, or by including your piece of code in a loop.

```
name = "Bob" ## or maybe you could ignore that
while True:
    try:
        print "Whats your name?"
        name = raw_input("Name:")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print name
        raw_input("PRESS ENTER TO RESUME")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The except block is inside the while loop. As soon as the *try* .. *except* block is finished, the code will reach the end of the while iteration, which means it will just repeat the iteration starting at *try*. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Yoou can't just assume anything without being given a relevant  requirement by the OP. Since this answer has been accepted, it's likely it suited them at the time or they were able to adapt it to whatever they wanted the code to do at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code above in a function that will then call itself.

```
def run_prog():
    name = Bob
    try:
        While True:
            print "Whats your name?"
            name = raw_input("Name:")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print name
        raw_input("PRESS ENTER TO RESUME")
        run_prog()

run_prog()
```

Comment: You might get a stack overflow after so many exceptions. Your stack will be getting bigger and bigger with each exception as the calling function won't quit until all above will

Comment: @Ritave really? is that the case for recursive functions in general? Do you have a source?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_deep_recursion

Some programs and intepreters (such as Python) have a set limit for recursion depth before terminating your script. In Python you can set it to something different though: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit

Comment: @Ritave so you don't get a stack overflow then. you get a RuntimeError :P Thanks for pointing that out, I don't use recursion in python often, but I will now keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

You can't really return to what was in the try block as the whole stack in the try-block is dropped when catching an exception.

In your example what I would do is:

```
name = None
while name is None:
    try:
        print "Whats your name?"
        name = raw_input("Name:")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raw_input("PRESS ENTER TO GO BACK TO NAME ENTRY")
print name
```

Answer (score 0):

after this function was interrupted by a KeyboardInterrupt, it is possible to resume the program by pressing ENTER:

```
def go (Teilungen, Faktor, d):
    Faktor = abs (Faktor - 1)
    funcs = [Step1, Step2, Step3, Step4, Step5, Step6, Step7, Step8]
    if d == 1: 
        text = "retour"
        funcs = funcs [::-1]
    else: text = "vor"
    for i in range (Teilungen):
        for func in funcs:
            try:
                func (Faktor)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                func (Faktor)
                print ("Funktion pausiert", text, "in", func, "in Teilung", i)
                inp = input ("Fortsetzen mit ENTER")
                print ("Es wird fortgesetzt ...")
```

for your example i do not see the need of using try as this will do what you want (Ctrl-C interrupts execution):

```
while True:
    print ("Whats your name?")
    name = input ("Name:")
    print (name)
```